# EC2 and Wordpress Times Out When Downloading Anything

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I put up a WordPress site on an EC2 instance (Linux, micro).   I couldn't get the install of WordPress using ssh command line because it would constantly time out.  But I did get it working by Ftping the files to my server.  Now, everything is working but when I try to install a new theme or plugin through the wordpess admin interface, I only get the timeout error.

I have no idea why I'm getting timeouts when I connect to the www.wordpress.com site (for the install or plugins or themes), but that seems to be the common denominator.

Does anybody know what might be going on here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I forgot to include https for outbound connections in the security group.